# Serverless framework - New variables resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

When I run `sls offline` - I'm facing a deprecation warning:

> Serverless: Deprecation warning: Variables resolver reports following resolution errors:
> - Variable syntax error at "functions.Test.environment.TEST_URL": Invalid variable type at index 20 in "${file(./env.yml):${'${self:provider.stage}.TEST_URL'}}"
> From a next major this will be communicated with a thrown error.
> Set "variablesResolutionMode: 20210326" in your service config, to adapt to new behavior now

[Documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#NEW_VARIABLES_RESOLVER) is not clear about it.

env.yml

```yaml
dev: 
  TEST_URL: https://example.com/
```

serverless.yml

```yaml
frameworkVersion: '2'

...

functions:
  Test:
    handler: handler.test
    environment:
      TEST_URL: ${file(./env.yml):${'${self:provider.stage}.TEST_URL'}} # <-------
```

It works correctly with frameworkVersion (>=1.1.0 <2.0.0).

What is a new approach to get data from another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a new approach to get data from another file

```yaml
environment:
    TEST_URL: ${file(./env.yml):${self:provider.stage}.TEST_URL}
```

Comment: What does the `env.yml` look like? Can you update your answer ans show us a sample please? Also, is some other plugin required for this to work? For example the [serverless-dotenv-plugin](https://github.com/neverendingqs/serverless-dotenv-plugin)?

Comment: @J86 https://github.com/dm-grinko/serverlessguru-test